# I want to learn how to network to add functionality to my XNA game

Tags: c#, networking, xna

How do I learn how to do this? Is there any good resources you know of?

Because I want to learn game programming, I want to learn UDP sockets not TCP sockets...

I searched google but I could not find anything good that was not outdated :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415171/confused-about-sockets-with-udp-protocol-in-c-sharp

Comment: Be sure to check out the [Lidgren (gen3)](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/) library. Either this will be a helpful resource for how you might wrap UDP to make it suitable for game networking. Or it will save you a lot of time - because you don't have to implement any of that stuff yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that XNA gives you only limited networking functionality, because the games are supposed to run on Games Live platform, so your options are:

- Local (split screen)
- SystemLink - local subnet
- PlayerMatch - XBox live servers
- Ranked - XBox live servers

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.net.networksessiontype%28v=XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx

The transport level is pretty much abstracted from you, so if you want to dive deep into TCP/UDP (and chose one over another). you should abandon native XNA networking, and just use `System.Net`. This will work only for desktop games.

You may start reading from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163648.aspx